# XSD od:tableProperty

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to generate a XSD file as following:

```
<xsd:schema>
  <xsd:element name="dataroot">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="sys_lookups" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="generated" type="xsd:dateTime" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="sys_lookups">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:appinfo>
        <od:index index-name="PrimaryKey" index-key="lookup_group lookup_value " primary="yes"
        unique="yes" clustered="no" order="asc asc" />
        <od:tableProperty name="Orientation" type="2" value="0" />
        <od:tableProperty name="OrderByOn" type="1" value="0" />
        <od:tableProperty name="NameMap" type="11" value="CswOVQAAAAAM8V6233tZSa18EF/EE1ddAAAAAMKLl3SLseNAAAAAAPgDAABzAHkA cwBfAGwAbwBvAGsAdQBwAHMAAAAAAAAABAYOkgXfa0WRIWHmYxfAYQcAAAAM8V62 33tZSa18EF/EE1ddbABvAG8AawB1AHAAXwBnAHIAbwB1AHAAAAAAAAAAvzD1RGJn 8kWa0lYnVRxv2QcAAAAM8V6233tZSa18EF/EE1ddbABvAG8AawB1AHAAXwB2AGEA bAB1AGUAAAAAAAAA05MSrGDnGkShEFWKASLxOAcAAAAM8V6233tZSa18EF/EE1dd cwBvAHIAdABfAG8AcgBkAGUAcgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAAAAQA 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA== "
        />
        <od:tableProperty name="DefaultView" type="2" value="2" />
        <od:tableProperty name="GUID" type="9" value="DPFett97WUmtfBBfxBNXXQ== " />
        <od:tableProperty name="DisplayViewsOnSharePointSite" type="2" value="1" />
        <od:tableProperty name="TotalsRow" type="1" value="0" />
        <od:tableProperty name="FilterOnLoad" type="1" value="0" />
        <od:tableProperty name="OrderByOnLoad" type="1" value="1" />
        <od:tableProperty name="HideNewField" type="1" value="0" />
      </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="lookup_group" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="text" od:sqlSType="nvarchar">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnWidth" type="3" value="7140" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnOrder" type="3" value="1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnHidden" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="Required" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="AllowZeroLength" type="1" value="1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="DisplayControl" type="3" value="109" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="IMEMode" type="2" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="IMESentenceMode" type="2" value="3" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="UnicodeCompression" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="TextAlign" type="2" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="AggregateType" type="4" value="-1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="GUID" type="9" value="BAYOkgXfa0WRIWHmYxfAYQ== " />
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:maxLength value="128" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="lookup_value" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="text" od:sqlSType="nvarchar">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnWidth" type="3" value="-1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnOrder" type="3" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnHidden" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="Required" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="AllowZeroLength" type="1" value="1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="DisplayControl" type="3" value="109" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="IMEMode" type="2" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="IMESentenceMode" type="2" value="3" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="UnicodeCompression" type="1" value="1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="TextAlign" type="2" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="AggregateType" type="4" value="-1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="GUID" type="9" value="vzD1RGJn8kWa0lYnVRxv2Q== " />
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:maxLength value="255" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="sort_order" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="longinteger" od:sqlSType="int"
        type="xsd:int">
          <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnWidth" type="3" value="-1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnOrder" type="3" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="ColumnHidden" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="DecimalPlaces" type="2" value="255" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="Required" type="1" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="DisplayControl" type="3" value="109" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="TextAlign" type="2" value="0" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="AggregateType" type="4" value="-1" />
              <od:fieldProperty name="GUID" type="9" value="05MSrGDnGkShEFWKASLxOA== " />
            </xsd:appinfo>
          </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have following questions about above xsd:

1. What is the value for tableproperty "NameMap" and is it encrypted. If yes then how?
2. Is the "GUID" 128 bit but encrypted. If yes then how?

I am new to XML and XSD so please forgive me if they are silly questions ;).

Thanks in advance,
KS

Comment: The attributes contain [Base64-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) binary values. They are not encrypted.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, but what are the values which have been encoded?

Comment: Well, the GUIDs are... GUIDs, pretty obviously. The NameMap is some internal property that MS Access uses for its ["Name AutoCorrect" feature](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/10895_3403871_4), as it appears.

Comment: Ok, but when I tried to decode the base64 value i.e. "BAYOkgXfa0WRIWHmYxfAYQ==" using online decoder tools with UTF-8 output charset, its not returing the valid string. Howz this possible?

Comment: The string represents a raw binary value that is not representable as a string. Since you cannot use raw binary in XML, the Base64 encoding is used. There is no telling what that binary value means to Access, it is an internal feature and Access is closed source.